# % calculation doesn't seem correct in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I drew a ***Metric using TSVB*** by following the excellent article https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-display-data-as-a-percentage-in-kibana-visualizations
So far so good.
But when I am calculating the % manually, its no where correct.

[image]

The query which I used:
For **Numerator** ->

```
eventName.keyword  :UPLOAD_STAGE  and payload.document.status.keyword:VALID_DOCUMENT  and payload.document.type.keyword:Passport
```

I received a count as **55** in discover tab

For **Denominator**->

```
eventName.keyword :RETRIEVAL_STAGE
```

I received a count as **926** in Discover tab

So if I calculate the percentage manually, it  comes as **5.9**

However Kibana is showing as ***68%***.

I am bit confused. Is there anything wrong with my approach?
Why am I having different percentage calculation result?
Looking forward to help me understand the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower case "and" was creating a problem. however this was fixed in 7.10 version onwards.